# Ubuntu on chromebook touchpad stopped working

Tags: chromebook

Touchpad isn't working today when I turned on my c720.

Maybe some kind of update erased my config or something? Idk, I don't know the linux. :(

Answer (score 0):

For this, you will have to open a Terminal window (`Ctrl + Alt + T`). Then run this command:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
```

Press ENTER, insert password and press ENTER again. Now your touchpad should be working. If you restart your computer and the touchpad does not work again, you will have to make a script to activate the touchpad every time Ubuntu boots. This is simple. In a terminal, run these commands, **one by one**:

```
sudo su
```

Here you will (maybe) be asked for your password, type it and press ENTER.

```
echo '#!/bin/bash' >> $HOME/mouse.sh
echo 'modprobe -r psmouse' >> $HOME/mouse.sh
chmod 777 $HOME/mouse.sh
cp $HOME/mouse.sh /etc/init.d
```

And we are done! The next time you boot into Ubuntu, the touchpad function will be back!

Comment: Are 777 permissions really necessary?

Comment: They are not REALLY necessary but this is not an extremely important/nocive script, I do not think 777 permissions are a problem.

Comment: And the question poster might want to edit the file (mouse.sh), if permissions were not 777 he would not be able to edit/execute it as a non-root user.

Comment: Yea, umms. I messed something up. Now my keyboard isn't working either, can't even log in to try this solution. :(